# Output of jStack

Tags: aem, thread-dump, jstack

We are using Adobe AEM on a windows machine.
Our Author instances get very slow and to investigate the same we try to take thread dumps by using the command 
jstack.exe pid > output file

The problem is that the output of this command is not same always.
Below are the two different output obtained.

This one hardly gives any info as to which thread is blocked

```
 Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 636: (state = BLOCKED)
- java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
- org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.TopicRoundRobinJobQueue.take() @bci=32, line=98 (Interpreted frame)
- org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue() @bci=14, line=454 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue) @bci=1, line=50 (Interpreted frame)
- org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run() @bci=56, line=137 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=722 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 635: (state = BLOCKED)
- sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=722 (Interpreted frame)


 Thread 634: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=722 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 633: (state = BLOCKED)
- sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=722 (Interpreted frame)
```

And below is the second output

```
2015-03-12 11:53:07
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode):

"Thread-49205" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc69000 nid=0x1c48 in Object.wait() [0x000000004925f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.LinkedQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x000000061148ca10> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49203" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc69800 nid=0x1f90 in Object.wait() [0x0000000048e5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.LinkedQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x000000061148ca10> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49202" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6c000 nid=0x9c0 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000004835f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.internalAdd(DefaultAuditLog.java:208)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000625c66710> (a com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.add(DefaultAuditLog.java:203)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.event.PageEventAuditListener.handleEvent(PageEventAuditListener.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:109)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49200" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6d800 nid=0x1a34 in Object.wait() [0x0000000048d5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.LinkedQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x000000061148ca10> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49168" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc67800 nid=0x1ca0 in Object.wait() [0x000000004ac5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.LinkedQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x000000061148ca10> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49166" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6c800 nid=0x1ed0 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000004965f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.internalAdd(DefaultAuditLog.java:208)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000625c66710> (a com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.add(DefaultAuditLog.java:203)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.event.PageEventAuditListener.handleEvent(PageEventAuditListener.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:109)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49121" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6f000 nid=0x19f8 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000004935f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.internalAdd(DefaultAuditLog.java:208)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000625c66710> (a com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.add(DefaultAuditLog.java:203)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.event.PageEventAuditListener.handleEvent(PageEventAuditListener.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:109)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49111" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6b000 nid=0x21d8 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000048f5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.internalAdd(DefaultAuditLog.java:208)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000625c66710> (a com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.add(DefaultAuditLog.java:203)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.event.PageEventAuditListener.handleEvent(PageEventAuditListener.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:109)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-49109" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6a800 nid=0x18ac waiting for monitor entry [0x000000004875f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.internalAdd(DefaultAuditLog.java:208)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000625c66710> (a com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.add(DefaultAuditLog.java:203)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.event.PageEventAuditListener.handleEvent(PageEventAuditListener.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:109)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Thread-48974" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc68000 nid=0x1f84 in Object.wait() [0x000000004945e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.WriterPreferenceReadWriteLock$WriterLock.acquire(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x0000000613135e20> (a EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.WriterPreferenceReadWriteLock$WriterLock)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.AbstractJournal.internalLockAndSync(AbstractJournal.java:295)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.AbstractJournal.lockAndSync(AbstractJournal.java:284)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.DefaultRecordProducer.append(DefaultRecordProducer.java:51)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.cluster.ClusterNode$WorkspaceUpdateChannel.updateCreated(ClusterNode.java:599)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager$Update.begin(SharedItemStateManager.java:565)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.beginUpdate(SharedItemStateManager.java:1462)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.update(SharedItemStateManager.java:1492)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:400)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.XAItemStateManager.update(XAItemStateManager.java:354)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:375)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SessionItemStateManager.update(SessionItemStateManager.java:275)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.perform(ItemSaveOperation.java:258)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.save(ItemImpl.java:329)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionSaveOperation.perform(SessionSaveOperation.java:64)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:361)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:812)
    at com.day.crx.core.CRXSessionImpl.save(CRXSessionImpl.java:131)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.internalAdd(DefaultAuditLog.java:215)
    - locked <0x0000000625c66710> (a com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog)
    at com.day.cq.audit.impl.DefaultAuditLog.add(DefaultAuditLog.java:203)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.event.PageEventAuditListener.handleEvent(PageEventAuditListener.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:109)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue CQ Workflows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc6e000 nid=0x1db8 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000048b5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.PersistenceHandler.lock(PersistenceHandler.java:1080)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000613341df0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.JCRJobEvent.lock(JCRJobEvent.java:39)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.executeJob(AbstractJobQueue.java:473)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractParallelJobQueue.start(AbstractParallelJobQueue.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue CQ Workflows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000002cc66000 nid=0x1b50 in Object.wait() [0x000000004ab5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.TopicRoundRobinJobQueue.take(TopicRoundRobinJobQueue.java:98)
    - locked <0x000000066bdaf770> (a java.util.HashMap)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:454)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush8" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020dc5000 nid=0x2070 in Object.wait() [0x000000004aa5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:72)
    - locked <0x000000066ab02158> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush7" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020dc6800 nid=0x15d0 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000004a15f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.PersistenceHandler.lock(PersistenceHandler.java:1080)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000613341df0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.JCRJobEvent.lock(JCRJobEvent.java:39)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.executeJob(AbstractJobQueue.java:473)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:67)
    - locked <0x000000066ab004d8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush6" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020dbb800 nid=0x1414 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000004a05f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.PersistenceHandler.lock(PersistenceHandler.java:1080)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000613341df0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.JCRJobEvent.lock(JCRJobEvent.java:39)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.executeJob(AbstractJobQueue.java:473)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:67)
    - locked <0x000000066ab00218> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush5" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020dcc800 nid=0x1d18 in Object.wait() [0x0000000049f5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:72)
    - locked <0x000000066aafff58> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020db8000 nid=0x1230 in Object.wait() [0x0000000049e5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:72)
    - locked <0x000000066ab44ea8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush3" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020dc2000 nid=0x1b6c waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000049d5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.PersistenceHandler.lock(PersistenceHandler.java:1080)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000613341df0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.JCRJobEvent.lock(JCRJobEvent.java:39)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.executeJob(AbstractJobQueue.java:473)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:67)
    - locked <0x000000066ab451a8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush2" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020db6800 nid=0x1fb0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000049c5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:72)
    - locked <0x000000066ab01828> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Apache Sling Job Queue com/day/cq/replication/job/flush12" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000020dc0000 nid=0x1594 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000049b5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.PersistenceHandler.lock(PersistenceHandler.java:1080)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000613341df0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.jcr.JCRJobEvent.lock(JCRJobEvent.java:39)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.executeJob(AbstractJobQueue.java:473)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.OrderedJobQueue.start(OrderedJobQueue.java:67)
    - locked <0x000000066ab01568> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.runJobQueue(AbstractJobQueue.java:461)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue.access$000(AbstractJobQueue.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.AbstractJobQueue$1.run(AbstractJobQueue.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Wanted to understand why the 2 different outputs.
Also the second output gives a very descriptive summary in tools like thread dump analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you observe is a difference between *normal* and *forced* jstack format. At least when using HotSpot's `jstack` implementation, the forced *format* needs to be requested explicitly by `-F` option. It is used in situations when *normal* threaddump can not be obtained as the application does not respond. The *forced* mode uses different mechanism to obtain the at least *some* data so it misses a lot of important information.

If I understand the question correctly, that particular `jstack` implementation chooses the output format automatically, presumably based on the application's ability to respond at the given moment. Consult the documentation if this can be turned off or use an alternative way to obtain the threaddump.